# How can i make this simple JQuery script shorter and better

Tags: jquery

I made simply script that changes Headings on select option. But i think that my code is too long for that simple script. I want to make this same script look better and shorter

Html:

```
<div class="main_text">
            <h1>Change Headings</h1>
        </div>


        <select id="selection">
            <option value="h1">H1</option>
            <option value="h2">H2</option>
            <option value="h3">H3</option>
            <option value="h4">H4</option>
            <option value="h5">H5</option>
        </select>
```

JQuery:

$(function() {

```
    $('select').change(function(){
         if ($(this).val() == 'h1') { 
            $(".main_text").html("<h1>Change Headings</h1>")
         } 

         if ($(this).val() == 'h2') { 
            $(".main_text").html("<h2>Change Headings</h2>")
         } 

         if ($(this).val() == 'h3') { 
            $(".main_text").html("<h3>Change Headings</h3>")
         } 

         if ($(this).val() == 'h4') { 
            $(".main_text").html("<h4>Change Headings</h4>")
         } 

         if ($(this).val() == 'h5') { 
            $(".main_text").html("<h5>Change Headings</h5>")
         } 
    });

});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kani339/ca1jdxx6/5/)

Comment: You could use 'else if' so each condition doesn't need to be tested, but provided it's readable, maintainable and it works leave it alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use concatenation and values:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    $(".main_text").html("<"+this.value+">Change Headings</"+this.value+">")
});
```

or another way to get it done, see the snippet below:

```js
    $('select').change(function() {
      var obj = $('<' + this.value + '>', {
        text: "Change Headings"
      });
      $(".main_text").html(obj);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main_text">
  <h1>Change Headings</h1>
</div>


<select id="selection">
  <option value="h1">H1</option>
  <option value="h2">H2</option>
  <option value="h3">H3</option>
  <option value="h4">H4</option>
  <option value="h5">H5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: are you sure `this.value` will work? I guess you should use `$(this).val()`

Comment: @RajanGoswami both are same jquery has a diff syntax but more keypresses. although i have added a demo too.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:-

```
$('#selection').change(function () {
    var tag = $(this).val();
    $(".main_text").html("<" + tag + ">Change Headings</" + tag + ">");
});
```

[**`FIDDLE DEMO`**](http://jsfiddle.net/g54ndqa9/)

Answer (score 0):

First, you only need to execute `$(this).val()` once:

```
var result = $(this).val();
if (result == 'h1') {
   // etc.
```

And since your conditions are mutually exclusive and all check the value of a single variable, you can use a `switch` statement instead of a bunch of `if` statements.  (That way you're not checking conditions that logically *can't* be true after finding one that is true.)

Though, looking at what the code *does* in those statements, you can refactor that into a kind of [template code](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/formTemplateMethod.html):

```
$(".main_text").html("<" + result + ">Change Headings</" + result + ">");
```

That way you only have to execute one line of code.  Re-name the variable to something sensible and you've refactored:

```
var tagName = $(this).val();
$(".main_text").html("<" + tagName + ">Change Headings</" + tagName + ">");
```

Depending on what `this` is, you might even get away with referencing a `.value` property directly and not having to execute the jQuery function at all:

```
$(".main_text").html("<" + this.value + ">Change Headings</" + this.value + ">");
```

Comment: Not to be "that guy", but would the down-voter care to comment on how this can be improved?

Comment: i guess that person is not able to read this, i would say this is the much detailed answer.